# remove records if particular cell have NA

Tags: r

if want to filter data on the basis of ID columns . so if ID columns have NA in all three columns then filter data
for example create a subset of df5 if id1 id2 and id3 column have NA

```
df5 <- structure(list(name = c("ka","au","wa","ny","de","ws","ol","yb","uy","hj"),
  `ID 1` = c(653, NA, 240, NA, 826, 872, 556, 440, 
 NA), `ID 2` = c(385, NA, 970, 240, 551, 854, 460, NA, NA),
 `ID 3` =c(385, NA, 970, NA, 551, 854, 460, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
      -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You could do `df5[!is.na(df5$'ID 1') & !is.na(df5$'ID 2') & !is.na(df5$'ID 3'), ]`

Comment: `df5[rowMeans(is.na(df5[,grepl("ID",colnames(df5))]))<1,]`

Comment: I want to make the the selection of column names dynamic, sometime column can be 3,4, or 9 etc

Comment: Check out `tidyr::drop_na()`

Answer (score 0):

**code**

```
df5[complete.cases(df5[ , 2:4]), ]
```

**output**

```
  name ID 1 ID 2 ID 3
1   ka  653  385  385
3   wa  240  970  970
5   de  826  551  551
6   ws  872  854  854
7   ol  556  460  460
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach, which will **ONLY** filter rows that are **ALL NA** (i.e. rows with 2 `NA`s or 1`NA` are retained).

Also in your comment, you mentioned you would like to have dynamic column names, I also included this in my answer. It will sum up the number of `NA`s in each row with column names that starts with `ID`, and filter away rows that are have `ncol() - 1` number of `NA` (since you don't count the `name` column, therefore you need the `- 1`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df5 %>% rowwise() %>% 
  filter(sum(is.na(c_across(starts_with("ID")))) != ncol(df5) - 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  name    ID1   ID2   ID3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ka      653   385   385
2 wa      240   970   970
3 ny       NA   240    NA
4 de      826   551   551
5 ws      872   854   854
6 ol      556   460   460
7 yb      440    NA    NA
```